# how to retrieve the value from html form text boxes created in the microsof bot framework?

Tags: node.js, nodes, bots, botframework

I am able to create the form with some HTML controls like text boxes(input fields) please find the screenshot given below.

Can you please let me know how to retrieve the values of the form fields(text boxes/Password fields) created in the bot.

```
bot.dialog('message_with_table', function (session) {
var tableHTML = '<table style="padding:10px;border:1px solid black;"><tr style="background-color:#c6c6c6"><th>Countries</th><th>Capitals</th><th>Population</th><th>Language</th></tr><tr><td>USA</td><td>Washington D.C.</td><td>309 million</td><td>English</td></tr><tr><td>Sweden</td><td>Stockholm</td><td>9 million</td><td>Swedish</td></tr></table>';
var message = {
    type: 'message',
    textFormat: 'xml', 
    text: tableHTML
};
session.send(message);});
```

[image]

I have impemented this using waterfall dialog. But, I need to implement this using html forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending which channels you are using... HTML is not supported in most channels, and I do not think there is actually a way to get the value of your textboxes.  One solution would be a [login card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments), another solution would be adaptive cards [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots) and [official site](http://adaptivecards.io/).

Answer (score 2):

As @JasonSowers said, XML type message is not supported in most channels, I suggest you can leverage [Input Form](http://adaptivecards.io/samples/InputForm.html) in [Adaptive Card](http://adaptivecards.io/), which is easy to generate a form for your user and also easy to get the input data from your user. You can refer to the answer of [Retrieve data from input form adaptive card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204965/retrieve-data-from-input-form-adaptive-card/47217798#47217798) for how to recieve data from imput form adaptive card.